# Get predict in TensorFlowLite for Swift

Tags: swift, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I launch code in this instruction: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_swift

Everything works, but I don't understand how to get the prediction values. I tried: `print(outputTensor` but got:

```
Tensor(name: "Identity", dataType: TensorFlowLite.Tensor.DataType.float32, shape: TensorFlowLite.Tensor.Shape(rank: 2, dimensions: [1, 3]), data: 12 bytes, quantizationParameters: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this part from the example guide

```
 // Copy output to `Data` to process the inference results.
  let outputSize = outputTensor.shape.dimensions.reduce(1, {x, y in x * y})
  let outputData =
        UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float32>.allocate(capacity: outputSize)
  outputTensor.data.copyBytes(to: outputData)
```

Then just print outputData buffer